# Image appears in preview but will not appear when I start the program

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio, ironpython

I am new to visual studio and WPF Iron Python development. I am trying to load a window with an image. The image appears in the xmal preview. However, when I start the program in visual studio, just a white window with no image appears.

Iron Python code

```
import wpf
from System.Windows import Application, Window

class MyWindow(Window):
    def __init__(self):
        wpf.LoadComponent(self, 'TestApp.xaml')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Application().Run(MyWindow())
```

xmal code

```
<Window 
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
       Title="SOC_Workups" Height="446.615" Width="767.993">
    <Grid>
        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="78" 
               VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="229" Margin="261,160,0,0"
               Source="images/logo.png"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Not sure about Iron Python, but usually the `Build Action` of the image file should be set to `Resource`. And of course the file should be part of the Visual Studio project, in a project folder named `images`.

Comment: try to set the source to Source="/images/logo.png"